# Will reformatting a corrupt SD card fix it?

Tags: boot, partitioning, sd-card, raspberrypi

I tried creating an Ubuntu Mate installation on a new SD card today.  The Raspberry Pi would not boot (only Red LED lights up) so and I checked the SD card with:

```
ole:$ sudo fsck -y -b 163840 -B 4096 /dev/mmcblk0p1  
fsck from util-linux 2.29
 e2fsck 1.43.4 (21-Nov-2017)
 fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open 
 /dev/mmcblk0p1

 The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid 
 ext2/ext3/ext4
 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an 
 ext2/ext3/ext4     
 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the 

 superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
 e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

I also tried running e2fsck with alternate superblocks, but it seems they are all bad.  However running `badblocks` did not report any errors.

```
ole@mki:~/Downloads$ sudo badblocks -o ./badblocks.list -w -s -v -b 4096 -c 16 /dev/mmcblk0p1 
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 7817983
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done                                                 

Reading and comparing: done                                                 

Testing with pattern 0x55: done                                                 

Reading and comparing: done                                                 

Testing with pattern 0xff: done                                                 

Reading and comparing: done                                                 

Testing with pattern 0x00: done                                                 

Reading and comparing: done                                                 

Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Can reformatting the card fix the errors?  I tried reinstalling the image onto the card 3 times, but that did not help, so just curious whether it's possible that it's simply a formatting issue?

### Update

I reformatted the whole thing using the ubuntu disk utilities, and now it appears to be ok:

```
ole:$ sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1 
fsck from util-linux 2.29
fsck.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
/dev/mmcblk0p1: 1 files, 1/1953541 clusters
```

I'm going to try writing the Ubuntu Mate image again and see if the Raspberry Pi will boot it.

### Another Update

Tried burning Ubuntu Mate onto it and after I'm done it the card will not mount in Nautilus and it still will not boot the Raspberry Pi:

```
ole@$ sudo ddrescue -D --force ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img /dev/mmcblk0p1
GNU ddrescue 1.21
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:    4999 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:   6550 kB/s
     opos:    4999 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:  13192 kB/s
```

non-tried:        0 B,     errsize:        0 B,      run time:      6m 19s
  rescued:    5000 MB,      errors:        0,  remaining time:         n/a
    percent rescued: 100.00%      time since last successful read:          0s
    Finished

Comment: Have you checked the validity of your downloaded image?

Comment: Yes - I'm about to ask another question of why it's corrupting the Ubuntu Mate installation is corrupting the SD card.  I'll include the sha256 sum test in that question.  I tried the whole thing with StartupDiskCreator and the Raspbian image and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  Reformatting the disk worked in this case.  To officially test it out I installed Raspbian instead of Ubuntu Mate and now it works fine.

Here's a [follow up question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978813/ubuntu-mate-installation-corrupts-sd-card) regarding the corruption that happens when I install Ubuntu Mate.